# How can you solve $y'(x) + p(x) y(x) = p(x) \sin \left( \dfrac{1}{x+1} \right), \ x \geq 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

We have
\begin{align}
y'(x) + p(x) y(x) = p(x) \sin \left( \dfrac{1}{x+1} \right), \ x \geq 0
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
p(x) = (x+1) \prod_{k=1}^{2021}(x-k), \ x \geq 0
\end{align}
can this be solved by the usual ODE methods?

Obviously the solution will be (since it's first order)
\begin{align}
y(x) = e^{-\int p(x) dx} \left\{ c+ \int p(x) \sin \left( \dfrac{1}{x+1} \right) e^{\int p(x)dx} dx \right\}
\end{align}
but where can we go from here?

Comment: I think the expression you wrote is as explicit as you can get. I tried solving it with $k = 1$ but didn't manage to get anything explicit.

Comment: Well the only step forward is to see that the integral from the right can be integrated by parts to produce a bounded solution but other than that I think it's over. Maybe I will solve it down the comments